# Shibboleth.sso 404 error on Windows IIS 10.0

Tags: iis, shibboleth

I have installed Shibboleth on Windows 2016 with IIS 10.0 and am working through configuring it as a Service Provider. I am trying to view this URL on my local server:

https://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status

...but I just get an HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. There is nothing in the Shibboleth Event Viewer for this error.

I do not see anything in ISAPI Filters or Handler Mappings related to Shibboleth, which is what I would assume the server needs in order to properly handle a file with extension SSO. Should there be something there? Nothing was added there as part of the installation process, nor did I see any documentation stating that I was supposed to.

Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: With IIS 7 or later, Shib doesn't install an ISAPI handler any more, instead it's a plugin... so I don't think you should see anything in the ISAPI filters or handler mappings any more.

Run `%SHIBSP_PREFIX%/sbin/shibd.exe -check` where `%SHIBSP_PREFIX%` is very likely `C:\opt\shibboleth-sp' and see if your config is valid?

Comment: When I run that statement I get "overall configuration is loadable, check console or log for non-fatal problems" which I assume is the desired response. Thanks so much for the explanation, that clarifies things. I also don't actually have "localhost" setup as a website. When I connect to a specific website I configured, I get a "identity provider not found" error, but that is a whole separate issue. At least I can be reasonably sure the software is installed and running now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the actual URL and IP address. This is especially true if you have multiple sites on the server.